# Replace a string in a text file with a blank essentialy deleting it

Tags: php

So I was able to find and target the string I am having trouble deleting it(my solution is replacing it with a blank) and overwriting the line with the new blank in the txt file.

```
elseif ($inquiry=='delete'){
    $file= fopen("database.txt", "r+") or die("File was not found on server"); 
    $search = "/^[" . $Title . "%" . $Author . "%" . $ISBN . "%" . $Publisher . "%" . $Year . "]/i";

    //search function
    // What to look for

    // open and Read from file
    $lines = file('database.txt');//array

    foreach($lines as $line){
        // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
        if(preg_match($search, $line)){
            file_put_contents($file, preg_replace($search,'',$line));
            echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;entry deleted-<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;entry not found<br>";
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: str_replace does not do regex

Comment: how else can i locate the string if i do not use regex

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)
```

so in your case it should be

```
preg_replace('/^[HELLO%JIM%MY%MOM%FLED]/i','', $line)
```

With your updated code this should be your solution
the problem is you’re only writing the $search variable to the file so I think this should work for you

```
 file_put_contents($file, preg_replace($search,'',$file));
```

Comment: im having trouble overwriting the line with the blank in my text file

Comment: can i do anything to help you better assist me?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code :

1) You are mixing two methods, `fread()`/`fclose()` and `files()`/`file_put_contents()` that open and close files automatically.

2) `file_put_contents` needs a file name as first argument, not the file handler you provide to him.

3) Your regex is invalid (for your needs) : with the square brackets `[]` you will match all the lines that have at least one character in common with the author, title, ...

4) You need to put the "element deleted / element not found" message outside the loop.

Here is a solution with `file()` and `file_put_contents()` : read the file as an array, loop over this array until you find the element you want to delete, and remove it with `unset`. Then you can rewrite the whole file.

```
$search = "/" . $Title . "%" . $Author . "%" . $ISBN . "%" . $Publisher . "%" . $Year . "/i";

// open and Read from file
$filename = 'database.txt' ;
$lines = file($filename);

$found = false ;
foreach($lines as $i => $line){
    // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
    if(preg_match($search, $line)){
        unset($lines[$i]); // remove the line from the array
        $found = true ;
        break ; // if you are sure that you won't have duplicate lines, you can stop the loop after you find the element
    }
}

if($found)
{
    // rewrite the whole file
    file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $lines));
    echo "entry deleted";
}
else
{
    echo "entry not found";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was my first time working with regex files and php you were very helpful in helping me understand and fix the problem 5 stars for you